# Is it OK to put last name before first name if the name comes from a culture with such a feature?

Tags: word-order, names, surnames

I have recently noticed that my first name goes after my last name in my Stack Exchange account. In my native language (Russian) it is OK to put them in any order. How shall I put my name in English (I’ve never heard last name being used before first name in English)? By rules of which language/culture shall I abide?

Comment: Depends on which culture you wish to follow.

Comment: Anecdotally, I almost never see the last-name-first usage _except_ in culturally-specific contexts - that is, if Szabo Istvan is a Hungarian introducing himself to his American classmates, he will almost always do so as Istvan Szabo; at the school's Hungarian Club (a culture-specific context), he may introduce himself as Szabo Istvan.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I suppose, it might be done not to have Istvan’s American friends reckon «Szabo» to be their first name and refer to them this way :). On the other hand, I do not know about Hungarian, but in Russian it is more than common to refer to people with their last names, so, in a way, it would work (as my one-time Math teacher said: “If you got the right answer, you’ve made an even amount of mistakes.”)

Comment: Last, first when alphabetizing, checking off payments received, etc. Otherwise Russian seems to be the same as English. Alexander “Sasha” Zverev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every newspaper around the US tells us about "Xi Jinping".  They never write "Jinping Xi" in the US-standard order.

So certainly on an international board like this, use whatever order you prefer.

Comment: However, if you are asked for your name by a native English speaker, the order is always "first name [second name] family name."

Comment: It is not clear how the second paragraph of this answer follows from the first. 'Xi Jinping' is so well entrenched in English, that it would be confusing, to say the least, to suddenly encounter a news article in English about 'Jinping Xi'; it doesn't seem that one can use whatever one prefers. On the other hand, one also cannot extrapolate from the standard practice of rendering Chinese names in this way to a general answer to the OP's question, because, as @Jeff Zeitlin points out in a very apt comment, the practice is different with respect to Hungarian names.

Comment: @jsw29 I suppose the answerer used “Xi Jinping” to show that first name-last name is not always the case. The fact that the English-speaking people got accustomed to “Xi Jinping” to a degree “Jinping Xi” seems like a different name (at least at first) is a whole separate issue. If we speak about the name order we shall choose to introduce ourselves, the native we are making friends with is unlikely to have any expectations about the name order. At the end of the day, my name is not being tossed around as much as the Chinese leader’s :).