# Is "Mr. Last Name + First Name" correct in formal writing?

Tags: formality, letter-writing

I'm translating a formal letter to English.
With my previous knowledge of English, I translated names from Singapore and China using the format "Mr. First name + Last Name".

For example:

(1)
The order in Chinese: Wang (last name) Lili (first name)

Translated: Mr. Lili Wang

(2)
The order in Singaporean-format: Koh (last name) Sing (first name)

Translated: Mr. Sing Koh

However, my colleague stated that I have made mistakes in arranging the order of last and first names and insisted I go with "Mr. Last name + First name" for all names in the letter.

I understand in Singapore, it seems people always put last name first (though I'm also unsure of the use), but is my colleague correct? I also wonder if the order varies in different cultures (ex. Singapore v. England)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this for the address in the letter, or for the salutation? Please provide a little more context for your question.

Comment: It's reasonably well-known to English speakers that the Chinese put the family name before the given name (for instance, Chairman Mao is always referred to as Mao Tse-Tung/Zedong).

Comment: Yes, the order varies in other cultures. In American culture, it's first name then last name, though it's customary in formal correspondence to omit the first name.

Comment: It's very common in English to use Mr with the surname/family name and no first name (especially in the salutation at the start of a letter), so you could write "Dear Mr Koh". You can also omit Mr if you're giving the full name, particularly if addressing an envelope/parcel etc, but also at the start of a letter. https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/zv7fqp3/articles/zkq8hbk

Comment: All translation involves some interpretation in the process. I'd change the name order in the translation if I was sure which is the family name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I put my surname after my given name when I introduce myself?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262395/should-i-put-my-surname-after-my-given-name-when-i-introduce-myself)

Comment: Also related: [Is it OK to put last name before first name if the name comes from a culture with such a feature?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/546580/).